# assertEqual not works when testing equals of command output

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, command-line-interface

Here is what I output in my command:

```
$output->writeln("\033[37;42m Translations from " . $input->getArgument('bundle') . " imported successfully! \033[0m");
```

Here is what I get in command line with trim func to delete spaces:

```
trim($commandTester->getDisplay())
..string(69) " Translations from AcmeDemoBundle imported successfully! "
```

But when I run this:

```
$this->assertEquals(" Translations from AcmeDemoBundle imported successfully! ", trim($commandTester->getDisplay()));
```

I get:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-' Translations from AcmeDemoBundle imported successfully! '
+Binary String: ...
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the trim command is not doing anything, as it only removes SPACE chars by default. if you want to check the content of a string, use unpack function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior because your string in the output is:

```
"\033[37;42m Translations from AcmeDemoBundle imported successfully! \033[0m"
```

which has special characters at the beginning and the end of the string, but they are not the special characters that the *trim* function deletes, so, your real comparison is between the above string and:

```
 " Translations from AcmeDemoBundle imported successfully! "
```

Which are different strings, although you can not see the special characters in the output.

You could add the characters that you want to be deleted of the string specifying the second attribute of the *trim* function. You could see the specification here:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php

Comment: This should work: `$this->assertEquals(" Translations from AcmeDemoBundle imported successfully! ", trim($str, "\033[37;42m\033[0m"));`